# Deploy Unity3D in Windows Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, azure, unity-game-engine

I'm a bit stuck with the windows Azure plateforme. For now, I have a ASP.NET MVC 3 Web role running on Azure. But I want to deploy a Unity3D Web Player Application. How can I perform this task. I think it's quite the same if I want to deploy a flash application on a web page. Instead of a .swf file, I have a .unity3d file.
Did somebody performed some kind of thing ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You just need to have do two things:

1. Install Unity Web Player components in your Azure VM: To achieve that you just need a Startup task to download and install UnityWebPlayer.exe silently without UI. To learn more about Startup task see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/03/17/using-startup-task-in-windows-azure-detailed-summary.aspx)
2. Setup Unity3d Mime Type in IIS:

   2.1 http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/25/how-to-add-mime-types-with-iis7-web-config.aspx

   2.2 http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/28968/mime-settings-for-unity3d-file-type.html

That should be enough.

Comment: Really thanks, I will look after that. But for the moment another problem appeared. I need to upload my .unity3d file on my role instance. A cool way will be with a html form and controller. From what I understand, I need to upload the file in the E/.../approot folder. But how ?! Or maybe, I can use a storage and retrieve my file.

Comment: It is best to use  upload the file directly to Azure Storage from your ASP.NET page and when you want to play get it from Azure Storage. Alternatively you can also use ASP.NET Temp folder to upload the file but remember this will stay in your Azure VM and will not persist if VM is recycled due to any reason.

Comment: Ok, I understand. And what about storing it in the localstorage and specify to not erase on recycle.

Comment: I mean, I can store the file in the blob storage and redistribute to the vms in the local storage.

Comment: This will work only upto role is recycled. If any reason your VM was reimaged, everything in your local storage will be gone.

Comment: Ok, maybe the onstart method can arrange that. If I do a check at the onStart I can reupload the file.

Comment: Have you tried playing content directly from azure storage in Unity player or does the content must be on local file system?