# Unity3D Azure Access and Crossdomain

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine

For now, i'm running a Unity Web Player App in a Windows Azure WebRole as suggested here.

[Deploy Unity3D in Windows Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739720/deploy-unity3d-in-windows-azure)

I'm a bit stuck with my unity app. I just deployed my application on windows azure. For the details, I have my web player file at siteroot/0/.unity3d

I use Uniweb to communicate with my web role (same as the one where the .unity3d file is located, so, it's the same domain)

But when I send HttpPost to my http://asp.net page I got this exception : SocketPolicyClient1: Incoming GetPolicyStreamForIP

```
SocketPolicyClient1: About to BeginConnect to x.x.x.x:843

SocketPolicyClient1: About to WaitOne

SocketPolicyClient1: WaitOne timed out. Duration: 3002.1718

SocketPolicyClient1: Caught exception: BeginConnect timed out

Exception: Unable to connect, as no valid crossdomain policy was found
```

But I have a crossdomain.xml located at siteroot/0/

```
xml version="1.0"

cross-domain-policy

allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="1-65536"

cross-domain-policy
```

I don't know why my unity app don't communicate with my (same) http://asp.net webrole. It worked well when I built windows app but with web player it fails.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Do you have a link to your sample which I can test? This will help me to understand the problem faster and then I could provide more suggestion.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't provide any link but I can answer any of your question.

Comment: It's a bit strange to use a crossdomain.xml for the moment because they are on the same domain. And I opened an endpoint to authorize tcp for the port 843.

Comment: IF that is the case you need to open a TCP Endpoint and set it to use 843 port and the write code to bind your service using RoleEnvironment.* methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's strange. It don't use Uniweb anymore but the build in www class and it still gives me the SecurityException: No valid crossdomain policy available to allow access.
I have my .unity3d in the blob storage (not same domain)

Answer (score 1):

Based on above log I am suspecting that you did not bind the port correctly when the role starts. To get is done you need the following:

Add the following endpoint to your Azure Application:

```
<Endpoints>
 <InputEndpoint name="Unity3DPort843" protocol="tcp" port="843" />
</Endpoints>
```

After that in your Role OnStart() method you will need to do the following to start the listening on that port:

```
TcpListener Unity3DPortListener = new TcpListener(RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["Unity3DPort843"].IPEndpoint);
Unity3DPortListener.Start();
```

I am only suggesting above based on the problem description so please try and let me know if it worked or not.

Comment: Ok I already tried that but I did not bond anything. I just added an Endpoint. I will try what you explained but the binding needs to be done in the onStart ? Because in the .csdef we have Binding fields. Is there any link ?