# Windows Azure and Unity3d

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine, azure-web-roles

Been interested in Unity3d for certain projects for some time now, and decided to bite the bullet! I started toying around, and fancied the idea of running Unity3d in windows azure.

However, despite my efforts, I was unable to get this running!

Here is what I have tried so far:

Including the Deployment Output from unity directly with my deployment to azure. While it is probably to keep the unity3d file in blob storage in azure, this was just for testing purposes.

I have included the mime type to allow iis to use the unity file (via the web.config): 
Code:

```
<staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".unity3d" mimeType="application/vnd.unity"/>
    </staticContent>
```

Lastly, I have included the UnityWebPlayer.exe file, and added a Startup task to install the UnityWebPlayer on the server. Also here another best practice would be to download the file instead, as it would be the latest version, but again, only for testing at the moment . My service definition of the start up is below:

Code:

```
<Startup>
    <Task commandLine="UnityWebPlayer.exe /S" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
    </Startup>
```

I am curious to reach out to the community to see if anyone else has had any success getting their games to the cloud with windows azure?

EDIT:

I should add then when trying to deploy such a web role, the role is stuck cycling and never deploys. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know much about Unity, but why would you be installing the web player on the server?

Comment: I did a bit of searching, and it seems the server may need the webplayer plugged in, but for reasons I cant find. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739720/deploy-unity3d-in-windows-azure

Comment: I'm willing to bet you don't need that. A deleted comment on that thread says it wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out!

A shout out to smarx for pointing out that you DO NOT need to install the UnityWebPlayer on the server.

As to get the unity file to load correctly, you do have to add the mime type to IIS, it is as above, except without the "."!

Silly me.

Enjoy!

Comment: The `staticcontent` entry in the web.config adds the needed mime type. Your original works fine for me on an Azure hosted MVC site. Can you clarify exactly what you did?