# Unity3D Web Client loading Page error in Windows Server?

Tags: iis, unity-game-engine, loading

I have developed an Unity3d 3D Walk through and published it on the Web. When i uploaded to the Linux server, it works fine; However, when i uploaded to a windows server, I have problems.

Linux Server: 
http://www.mandanemedia.com/Staging/Unity3D/NUS3DWalkThrough/

Windows Server: 
http://skqs.nus.edu.sg/medicallibrary3d/

I think what's happening is that the Unity3D page is not accessible. To try it out yourself, go to [this link](http://www.mandanemedia.com/Staging/Unity3D/NUS3DWalkThrough/WebPlayer.unity3d), and you don't get an error. However, if you go to [this page](http://skqs.nus.edu.sg/medicallibrary3d/WebPlayer.unity3d), you will get an ISS error.

I've searched on Google to try and find a solution:

On the IIS Server, it must specify that a Unity3D file is something that is allowed to be sent over.

How to do it:
In web.config file on the home directory of IIS we need to configure the file to allow unity3d file to be loaded:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".unity3d" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".unity3d" mimeType="application/vnd.unity" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Further Links:

1. http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/14819-lots-of-customers-experience-invalid-Unity-file/page3
2. [Deploy Unity3D in Windows Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739720/deploy-unity3d-in-windows-azure)
3. http://developer.dynamicweb-cms.com/forum/development/adding-mime-types.aspx

And I've got the network admin of NUS to do this, below are screenshots of the server settings:

[alt text http://www.mandanemedia.com/Staging/Unity3D/NUS3DWalkThrough/image001.png](http://www.mandanemedia.com/Staging/Unity3D/NUS3DWalkThrough/image001.png)
[alt text http://www.mandanemedia.com/Staging/Unity3D/NUS3DWalkThrough/image002.png](http://www.mandanemedia.com/Staging/Unity3D/NUS3DWalkThrough/image002.png)

But the issue still exists. I would appreciate if anyone had any ideas on how to solve it. Thanks!

Comment: i find another useful link as http://www.iis.net/learn/web-hosting/web-server-for-shared-hosting/configuring-iis-for-silverlight-applications , but i do not have much experience in windows server :| .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the server is windows 2003 and  IIS6, as a result this method does not work in IIS6.

Through configure IIS6 we need to use IIS Manager User Interface in windows Server 2003:

1. Go to Start\Administrative Tools and run IIS Manager.
2. Right click on the server name and select Properties.
3. In the Properties dialog box, click MIME Types.
4. In the MIME Types dialog box, click New.   I
5. the MIME Types dialog box, enter the following MIME type:

   Extension:            .unity3d

   MIME type:       application/vnd.unity

It's done, Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I am also not an expert on IIS, but I remember there are some settings that dictate what file extensions IIS will serve to clients. Since the unity web project uses a special file extension ".unity" it seems like IIS has not been configured correctly. 
See:
[Unity3d Forum post on topic](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/11263-Setting-up-IIS-to-stream-Unity3D-content)

Answer (score 0):

This gets even more bizarre in IIS 7.5.  If I use the web.config method which I have been, it works just fine.  Since I manage the server, I decided I wanted to add it to the list of MIME types at the server level.  So at the server level I add:

extension:  .unity3d
mime type:  application/vnd.unity

All of the sudden ALL of my PNG images on multiple sites start returning 500 errors.  I remove the mapping at it works.

If I add the MIME Type at the "site" level instead of the server level in IIS configuration it works fine.  It appears to be an IIS bug.  Just an FYI if you run into it.

Comment: Yeah IIS is crazy and doesnt respect the scope of the UI. Changes at site level can and do affect the server level in some cases. People have complained about this. Try removing a mapping from one site, it affects other sites.